# Unhandled event loop exception in plugin org.eclipse.ui

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently installed/updated eclipse environment.  When I try to compile the code I'm getting the error as:

> Unhandled event loop exception

and says the error is in the `org.eclipse.ui` plugin-in.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Hi guys this is again one of the link that help you. I tried it, it works for me.[enter link description here](http://www.javaquery.com/2010/11/how-to-solve-permgen-space-error-in.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok please follow the following steps:

- First close your eclipse.
- Go to your Eclipse Folder
- You will find the "Features" & "Plugins" folders in it.
- Open the "Features" folder and search for the "org.eclipse.ui" folder or .jar file. If found then cut it & paste on desktop.
- Open the "Plugins" Folder and search for the "org.eclipse.ui" folder or .jar file. If found then cut it & paste on desktop.

Now start your eclipse & try to compile.

It's possible that while updating it has downloaded the wrong updates.

Comment: I have the same error. I found more than one folder and many jars in my plugins folder that has org.eclipse.ui in their names. Do i cut all of them or specific ones?

Comment: I have the same observation as Mido. for instance, extensions to the name like "org.eclipse.ui.browser_3.3.1.r36_20101216.jar." I see no plain "org.eclipse.ui" file in either the Features or Plugins folders.

Comment: I seemed to have similar issues with @Steve and Mido  :(

Comment: Me too found more than one jars in my plugin folder..
what shoud i have to do now??
should i deleted all jar files???

Comment: Tried with ganesh answer its working fine for me. I just clear all of my projects. And tried. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Finally after spending 2 hours trying to fix Eclipse, I just re-installed Eclipse and everything worked in the following 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

no need to worry.. if you running android application.. give eclipse some time... restart your computer after some times open eclipse clean all projects.. now try.. it working perfectly now.. :D

Comment: You are alright! I try to fix but it will not appear when restart computer :D

Comment: @ganesh Its working fine. I just clear all of my projects. And tried. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning all projects worked for me!

Comment: In conjunction to cleaning all of the projects, I also added this line

Answer (score 1):

I also had "Unhanded event loop exception" in Eclipse neon.3 on Linux Mint, and there were other problems such as the perspective button bar either not showing or else throwing an error when you attempted to configure it.

I found the solution in [comment #7 of an Eclipse bug discussion](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497705#c7).

The solution is to start eclipse after first executing these commands:

```
export SWT_WEBKIT2=1
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was not working for me but after digging through the internet it became clear that some other software is messing up eclipse.

In my case it was the hydra vision in the catalyst control center. As I can see *any* application that messing with window handling will or can cause this error, based on the variety of setups and background from other people who experienced this problem.

One of the best ways to determine which application is causing the problem (if it's an applicaion) is:

1. open the task manager
2. start killing processes (start with unknown or new or any video related driver).
3. After each process kill check eclipse (restart it each time, just in case)

and after killing hydra vision the error did not pop again (no restart was needed but who knows how other application works).

Hope this will help others to not spend a day on this annoying problem.

Best for all

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction to cleaning all of the projects as suggested by Michael Martin, I also appended this line in the eclipse.ini:

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Per this [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom).