# Eclipse runs out of handles

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am working using Eclipse Juno Version: 4.2.2 , but frequently I am facing a problem

Problem 1.
 [image]

And After clicking ok or cross button another screen is appearing.
 Problem 2.
 [image]

If I click no button then the dialog is disappearing and if I choose Yes then the Eclipse is closing.

Comment: Download the latest Eclipse Indigo instead. This may be a bug regarding your system configuration, etc.

Comment: What kind of project are you developing with juno?SWT?XWT?Jface?

Comment: when this problem occured? while you run / debug the program???

Comment: the link below will might help you...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074189/unhandled-event-loop-exception-in-plugin-org-eclipse-ui

Comment: I am Developing Android application , when I am opening a class file then this dialog appearing two times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bug in one of the Eclipse plugins that you use. They don't properly clean up resources (colors, fonts) so Eclipse eventually runs out of handles (= the OS won't give Eclipse any more resources).

The short term solution is to restart Eclipse.

If you want to file a bug report, install the [Sleak tool](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php) and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

For one try,
Please follow the following steps, First close your eclipse.

Go to your Eclipse Folder
you will find "Features" & "Plugins" folder in it.
Open "Features" folder and search for "org.eclipse.ui" folder or .jar file. If found then cut it & paste on desktop.
Open "Plugins" Folder and search for "org.eclipse.ui" folder or .jar file. If found then cut it & paste on desktop.
Now start your eclipse & try to compile.

It may be possible that while updation it has downloaded improper updation.

Comment: Maybe you should mention to only remove the latest version. But since 3.6, Eclipse knows for sure which JARs are on your disk (i.e. it doesn't read the files, it keeps a list) and if it can't find these JARs, it simply won't start anymore. So I doubt this will help with e4.

Comment: There are no such a folder of jar, but I found "org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524" this folder inside plugins.