# Android Java: Fatal exception main nullpointer. I do not have an explicitly defined Thread. It says it cannot instantiate the activity

Tags: android, exception, program-entry-point, unhandled

I have been looking around for answers on Unhandled loop Exception errors, but now I'm getting a new error, nullpointer that is preventing my Activity from working. My run says, "unfortunately [app] has stopped." I think my Unhandled loop Exception is related to this new Exception, because I read about it being related to Thread here: [a Wordpress blog](http://manuelselva.wordpress.com/2008/02/21/unhandled-event-loop-exception/)

I cannot seem to understand these errors. For the first, I tried following instructions to remove jar plugin and feature files from [Unhandled event loop exception in plugin org.eclipse.ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074189/unhandled-event-loop-exception-in-plugin-org-eclipse-ui) but this didn't seem to change the situation at all. Here is my stack trace:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: erinmargotmasterson.expandingthink.alpha, PID: 1273
    java.lang.RunTimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo(erinmargotmasterson.expandingthink.alpha/erinmargotmasterson.expandingthink.alpha.MainActivity): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.HandleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)`
```

..... etc, etc. Note: I actually typed all that out. I couldn't figure out how to save the whole thing to a log file...

Code from my MainActivity:

```
package erinmargotmasterson.expandingthink.alpha;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
cameraClass cameraView = new cameraClass(getApplicationContext());
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Button myCaptureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
myImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); 
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new  
PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
}
```

Nothing significant after that. My manifest xml is:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature 
android:name="android.hardware.camera"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="erinmargotmasterson.expandingthink.alpha.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

between the beginning and ending common manifest code.

Edit: The cameraClass.java from the [tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZp2gt9XmcQ) I mentioned is as follows:

```
package erinmargotmasterson.expandingthink.alpha;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
public class cameraClass extends SurfaceView implements Callback {
private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
public Camera camera = null;
public cameraClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sHolder.getSurface();
    sHolder.addCallback(this);  
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int format, int width, int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setPreviewSize(width, height);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(sHolder);
    } catch (Exception e) { //remember the exception parameter!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera = null;
}   
    public void capture(Camera.PictureCallback jpegHandler) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you stopped retyping the crash log before getting to the meaningful lines.  We'll need to see a few more, until it references code that you actually wrote yourself.

Comment: Did my answer work for you ?

Comment: @chris-stratton Yes, here is the rest of the stack trace.  `Caused by: Java.lang.NullPointerException at erinmargotmasterson.expandingthink.alpha.cameraClass.<init>(cameraClass.java:15) at erinmargotmasterson.expandingthink.alpha.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)` I was following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZp2gt9XmcQ) and I have another class from it, see edit above.

Comment: @user3293834 - that does seem to confirm Kedarnath's answer.  But you should edit this into your question itself, and then delete the comment.

Comment: Well I am not sure why but at least I learned to look for the cause in the crash log instead of the top. As a beginner, it was an understandable mistake, I should say.

Comment: @Kedarnath No, that answer did not work for me, but I resolved both the NullPointerException and subsequent problem in MainActivity (which I apologize as I forget what that error was called). See my below answer to my own question. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

move these lines

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Button myCaptureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

after this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

in onCreate() method.

So change your activity code to like below,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    cameraClass cameraView;
    ImageView myImageView;
    Button myCaptureButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        cameraView = new cameraClass(getApplicationContext());
        myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        myCaptureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); 
        if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new  
             PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be an issue that needs fixing.  And it should cause the given error message.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, IF OP still facing error and provide me new error log then I would like to solve his new errors :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be in this section:

```
public class cameraClass extends SurfaceView implements Callback {
private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
public Camera camera = null;
public cameraClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sHolder.getSurface();
    sHolder.addCallback(this);  
}
```

Note: I did not enter the rest of the methods and closing class bracket for brevity's sake. If it is relevant, please refer to it above in my original question.

sHolder was undefined. I guess you can't always trust tutorials. Then there was an error at the line in MainActivity:

```
myImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

I don't know why that is, but I did recently have incompatibility issues with certain themes and styles in Eclipse. Maybe someone could comment and enlighten me on the matter.